# What are the polar coordinates of $(2\sqrt3, 2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

My answer to this is $(4,\frac{π}6)$. But a calculator said that $(-4,\frac{7π}6)$ is also an answer, and there are infinitely many solutions. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution *is* correct. Now, concerning $\left(-4,\frac{7\pi}6\right)$, it is indeed true that$$-4\left(\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}6\right),\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}6\right)\right)=\left(2\sqrt3,2\right),$$but $-4<0$, and therefore that answer is wrong. And your answer is the only one which uses an angle from $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: $7\pi/6 \in [0, 2\pi)$

Comment: But $-4$ is negative.

Comment: @harpey By convention the first number in the polar form is a radius $r\ge 0$, it is positive since it is a distance from the origin. Even if $-4\exp(i7\pi/6)=4\exp(i\pi/6)$ the radius $r$ is still $4$ and only the rhs is the "true" polar form. The same for angles, they need to be in $[0,2\pi)$. Even though adding multiple of $2\pi$ doesn't changes the result, the polar form is the one with the angle in the conventional interval.